# How to write units in Java like Radian, Newton, Pascal, mm, kg?

Tags: java, mathcad

I am developing a Java application, its about converting Mathcad worksheet to Java application. Can anyone know/suggest how to write units(newton, pascal, mm, kg)in java code?

Example:1?

```
double var1 = 10*newton/mm;//looking for a way to write the code in this format.
double var2 = 5*mmpower2;
double var = var1/var2;
double var = ?
```

Example: 2?

```
double var1 = 90degress-tan(60)*Radian;
double var1 = ?
```

Comment: is this supposed to be java code? there is no var in java. for your problem you should create classes for each unit

Comment: yes, i mean double variable1 = ..;

Comment: Have a look at: http://jscience.org/

Comment: Take a look at the [`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class. It represents various time units, from nanoseconds to days, in a convenient manner.
Maybe you could take inspiration from this class when writing your own unit-related classes ?

Comment: thanks omer schleifer, that API is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Javax.units package](http://jsr-108.sourceforge.net/javadoc/javax/units/package-summary.html), especially the [Java Unit Class](http://jsr-108.sourceforge.net/javadoc/javax/units/Unit.html).

This is a well-studied problem and for any non-trivial program you should always use an existing units library.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your examples are sensible Java.

You want to implement the Martin Fowler Analysis Patterns idea of [Quantity](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html) with units.

There are libraries that exist, like [JScience](http://jscience.org/), but I don't know if they're in widespread use.

Comment: Bascially, I was looking for a way to write the code in that format. JScience and Unit seems to be the answer for this.